# OnClick function in SetAttribute is throwing argument undefined error in IE11

Tags: javascript

I am calling the function in the onClick using the setAttribute but getting undefined error for PolicyNumber.

Arguments are set as follows:

```
cqpViewLink.setAttribute("accountID", this._accountID);
cqpViewLink.setAttribute("nodeID", cqpID);
cqpViewLink.setAttribute("policyNumber", policyData.policyNumber);

cqpViewLink.setAttribute("onclick", 
"AccountTab.NavigateToCQPNode(this.accountID,this.nodeID, policyNumber);");
```

Below is the method called with the aruguments

```
AccountTab.NavigateToCQPNode = function (accountID, nodeID, policyNumber) 
 {
    window.location = "CQP?polnum=" + policyNumber.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "") 
    + "&userid=" + StpMain.userId;
    AccountTab.NavigateToTabNode(accountID, nodeID);    
 };
```

This was working fine with IE8 but got upgraded to IE11 which is throwing the undefined error for policyNumber with the script block as

```
function onclick(event)
{
   AccountTab.NavigateToCQPNode(this.accountID,this.nodeID, policyNumber);
}
```

Please someone do help me to resolve the error.

Comment: Where is `policyNumber ` is coming from? Other parameters have `this`, so, is it should be `this.policyNumber`?

Comment: Added the code from where the arguments are set for the function